# Quotient of 3-sphere by binary octahedral group?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, gr.group-theory, lie-groups, differential-topology, dg.differential-geometry

Consider the Lie group $Spin(3)$, which can be thought of geometrically as the 3-sphere (e.g., it can be represented by the collection of unit quaternions).  The quotient $Spin(3)/\pm I$ yields the group $SO(3)$ of rotations of $\mathbb{R}^3$.  The *octahedral group* $Oct$ is the symmetry group of the (regular) octahedron, i.e., it is the maximal subgroup of $SO(3)$ that maps the octahedron to itself.  The *binary octahedral group* $2Oct$ is simply the double cover of the octahedral group in the spin group.

**Question**: what is the quotient $Spin(3)/2Oct$ as a topological space?

Equivalently, what is the topology of $SO(3)/Oct$?  (And is there a natural geometry associated with this space?) Note that $Oct$ is not a normal subgroup of $SO(3)$, hence the quotient does not exist in the sense of groups---only in the sense of topological manifolds.

A closely related example is the quotient of $Spin(3)$ by the *icosahedral* group, i.e., the symmetries of the icosahedron in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  In that case, the quotient is the [Poincaré sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_homology_sphere#Poincar.C3.A9_homology_sphere).  I am basically looking for the analogous object in the octahedral case.

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "what is the quotient", what do you mean?  It's the quotient, you already have a definition as you gave it yourself.  It has spherical geometry.  Google "geometrization conjecture" and look up "spherical geometry".    Your action of the binary octahedral group on $S^3$ is by isometries, so the quotient inherits the same local geometry as $S^3$. 

Comment: What is it that you know about the Poincare sphere but don't know about this other manifold? It's homology? A description as a polytope with sides identified?

Comment: @Tom: right, I know that $SO(3)/Ico$ is a homology sphere, but I do not know the homology of $SO(3)/Oct$.

Comment: @Ryan: forgive me if I'm wrong, but it seems the group you describe there Q8={±1,±i,±j,±k} is only a subgroup of the binary octahedral group. (The group 2Oct has 48 elements.)

Comment: @Ryan it would also seem that $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ is not the abelianization of $2Oct$ but rather $Q_8$.

Comment: Ah whoops, it's a late night for me.  I was mistaking the octahedral and quaternion 8-group manifolds.  The manifold you're interested in does not embed in $S^4$, unfortunately.  I think the manifold you're interested in has homology $\mathbb Z_8$, you can derive it from a presentation for the fundamental group. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_octahedral_group

Comment: This 'octahedral group' is isomorphic to the symmetric group $S_4$. Its abelianization has order two, and the abelianization of the 'binary octahedral group' is the same.

Comment: It has different topological descriptions, as a Seifert-fibered space which is a bundle over a $(2,3,4)$ turnover (the unit tangent bundle to the $(2,3,4)$ turnover), or as a Dehn filling on the trefoil knot. It has a spherical geometry, and you can visualize flying through it with Jeff Weeks' program Curved Spaces:
http://www.geometrygames.org/CurvedSpaces/

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't try such computations when I'm so tired...  Is there anything else you'd like to know about this manifold, fuzzytron?  I think it has a genus-2 Heegaard splitting.   It has similarly nice representations as a branched covering space, closely related to the Seifert-fibering mentioned by Ian.  I don't think you can get this manifold by identifying faces of a platonic solid, but perhaps you can do it with an archimedian solid.  But I don't know of any special role this manifold has. 

Comment: @Ryan: a geometric description would indeed be nice, if you know of one.  Ideally, I'd like to realize this space in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  The context is something like nematic crystals, just with a different symmetry group.  You can imagine that the configuration of such a crystal is a section of a $SO(3)/Oct$ bundle over some domain.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Agol: thanks---any pointers as to how you get there?  Not really my forte. P.S. Beautiful program!

Comment: @fuzzytron: Jeff Weeks' name comes up after a cursory search through google (e.g., for `binary octahedral space'). See: http://arxiv.org/pdf/math.SP/0502566.pdf As for some `special role this manifold has', see, e.g., http://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0504656v1.pdf Perhaps literature related to the latter link would provide more relevant information.

Comment: fuzzytron, for more information about spherical manifolds in general, you might be interested in Peter Scott's article 'The geometries of 3-manifolds', Bulletin of the LMS, 1983.